# Is the following subset connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Is the following subset connected?

$A=\{a,d,e\}$ subset of a topological space $(X,\tau)$, $X=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ and $\tau = \{X,\phi,\{a,b,c\},\{c,d,e\},\{c\}\}$.

> My ans:

The closed sets of $\tau$ are given by $\{\phi,X,\{d,e\},\{a,b\},\{a,b,d,e\}\}$. Clearly the set $A \neq U \cup V$ for some U and V, both open (closed) in $\tau$.
Hence, the set $A$ is connected.

> But my solution key says this set is disconnected. what am I doing wrong here and also, is my idea to solve this question correct? Thanks.

Comment: You have to consider open sets for the induced topology on $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have that
$$A =\left(\lbrace a,b,c\rbrace \cap A\right) \cup \left(\lbrace c,d,e \rbrace) \cap A\right)$$

so $A$ can be written as the union of two open disjoints subsets of itself, for the topology on $A$ induced by the given topology on $X$. Therefore $A$ is not connected.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. Can you mention the theorem/result that you made use of while solving this question?

Comment: @s1mple It is just the definition of a (non-)connected subset : it can be written as the union of two open subsets **of itself**. The point is that you have to consider the topology on $A$ and not the topology on $X$.

Comment: Oh the subspace topology on $A$ induced by topology on $X$ you mean?

Comment: @s1mple Exactly

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are welcome !

Answer (score -1):

$A\subseteq\{a,b,c\}\cup\{d,e,c\}= U\cup V$ provides a disconnection of $A$. Although $U\cap V\ne\emptyset$,  this is not required for a disconnection. What *is* required is that $U\cap\{d,e\}=\emptyset=V\cap\{a\}$.

Comment: Why the downvote?